# How I add a regex function to SQLite in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need implement an application to list and categorize a lot information. I can't make changes on database schema, and I have a regexp to validation.

Unfortunable SQLite drive don't have a implementation to regexp, I need make a user custom function, but I'm breaking my head a lot with that.

I have a custom SQLite Dialect, and i try include my function in various forms.

```
public SQLiteDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction("regexp", new REGEXP());
}
```

Any help will great.

Comment: I see that wanser. But nothing works for me.

Comment: please explain how it is not working so others can help.

Comment: The answers above are using sqlite-jdbc. so they will not work for you. I will remove that.